# How to get the n-element in a list/array in Pandoc template

Tags: pandoc

In [Pandoc template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates), given an list/array `my_list` and an integer `n` (less than the list/array lenght/size), how can I get the n-element in the list/array?

### Minimal working example

`main.md` has

```
---
title: MWE
my_list:
  - one
  - two
  - three
---

Hello
```

`template.md` has

```
First: $my_list/first$

n-element:

Last: $my_list/last$
```

Execute `pandoc main.md --to markdown --template template.md` produces

```
First: one

n-element:

Last: three
```

### Environment

Pandoc version 3.1.2.